# Rsync over ssh in a cron job: connection fails

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync, cron

I have created a script in order to backup my files over ssh. The authentication method used is an rsa key without password.

```bsh
#!/bin/env bash

LOG_FILE="/home/toto/bin/backups.log"
DEST="/dest/"
IP=10.1.0.5

host_is_up () {
  ping -c 1 -W 2 $1 &> /dev/null
}

rsync_backup () {
  # add --dry-run to test with false rsync
  rsync --dry-run -r -a -v -e "ssh -i /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --delete $1 toto@$IP:$DEST --log-file=$LOG_FILE > /home/toto/bin/cron_output.log 2>&1
}

SRC="/home/toto/Music"


date > $LOG_FILE
if host_is_up $IP
then
  rsync_backup $SRC
else
  echo "Host $IP seems to be down" >> $LOG_FILE
fi
```

When I try to launch this script, everything is fine, the backup is done, I do not need to add a password.

The problem comes when I try to use this script in cron:

```
*/2 * * * * ~/bin/backups.sh
```

It does not work:

I have the following logs

```bsh
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/toto/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.0.5 [10.1.0.5] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.1.0.5:22 as 'toto'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: #################################################################################
debug1: Host '10.1.0.5' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/toto/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa RSA SHA256:############################################### explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa RSA SHA256:################################################# explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
toto@10.1.0.5: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ssh command tries to use the xxxx.pub file for authentication when it exists.

For example, if your backup.id_rsa.pub was not created from your private key backup.id_rsa properly for some reason, the publickey authentication would be failed with the following lines:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa RSA SHA256:################################################# explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

What will be happened if you rename or delete /home/toto/.ssh/backup.id_rsa.pub?

Comment: I don't understand why , but when I remove backup.id_rsa.pub I am still able to run the script "manually" but it does not work when launched with cron.

Comment: Thanks pointing me in the right direction. My problem was clearly a problem with my key. I added in my server authorized_keys file the private key instead of the public key. If you edit your answer a little saying something like "check you keys both on your client and server side" it would be great. thanks